# In google analytics, why do I see xyz.com page visits under abc.com account?

Tags: google-analytics, click-through

- I own abc.com
- Client owns xyz.com
- I manage google analytics accounts for both sites

Every once in a while I see abc.com?utm_source=foo(...) clickthrough links / page hits under xyz.com account and vice versa. What could be causing this?

I do not have client's tracking code installed on my site and client does not have mine. How does this stuff cross over?

Answer (score 0):

You and the client have mixed up the tracking IDs of both the account. Your Tracking ID is stored in some form on the client's website and vice versa.

Possible reasons may be-
1). They have created a pageview tag using your tracking ID in their GTM account and vice versa.
2). They are running an A/B test with specific UTM parameters using your tracking ID and vice versa.
You can check this using tag assistant extension in Google Chrome.

Comment: Hi, 

Thank you very much for your response. Unfortunately that is not the issue as the client never had access to my tracking ID (they don't even know what it is), nor have I ever installed their tracking id on my site.

I've noticed that it's only clickthroughs that cross over like this.. so perhaps it's an adwords issue?

Comment: Please share the exact campaign URL so that the issue can be checked further